# Use variable inside __init__ to outside __init__

Tags: python, django

I want to use a  variable inside `def__init__` outside of `def__init__`. This is the `def__init__` in my class :

```
class UserResponseSearchForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           qry = kwargs.pop('qry')
           super(UserResponseSearchForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I want to use variable **qry** outside `def__init__` like this :

```
class UserResponseSearchForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           qry = kwargs.pop('qry')
           super(UserResponseSearchForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
gejala_id1 = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Gejala.objects.all().values_list('gejala', flat=True).distinct().filter(gejala__icontains = qry).order_by('gejala'), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=False)
```

I use variable **qry** in **gejala__icontains = qry** like this:

```
filter(gejala__icontains = qry)
```

And it return **name 'qry' is not defined**. What the problem with that? And how to use the **qry** variable?
Hope anyone can help me.

Comment: Can you fix your indentation please? It’s unclear where you want to call things.

Comment: But you couldn't use it inside the `gejala_id1` definition anyway, as that is executed at *definition* time, not at run time.

Comment: But i must to use it inside `gejala_id1` to get the actual data

Comment: your `gejala_id1` field is defined outside the class `UserResponseSearchForm`, so you cannot use it anywhere in your django code anyway.  I think what you want is to define the field as part of your form, correct?

Comment: My `gejala_id1` is defined inside class `UserResponseSearchForm` and the `def __init__` inside that class too. So i want to use the `qry` variable inside `def __init__`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this inside `__init__`:

```
class UserResponseSearchForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qry = kwargs.pop('qry')
        super(UserResponseSearchForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['gejala_id1'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Gejala.objects.filter(gejala__icontains = qry).distinct().order_by('gejala'), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=False)
```

Note you should *not* do `values_list('gejala', flat=True)` for a `ModelMultipleChoiceField`, because this field expects the objects, not a flat list of strings.

Comment: Okay thanks, and how do i call to the html file and make it to multiple choice form?

Comment: You do that in your view. I suppose you are using the form somewhere... If you don't know how to render a django form, read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/)

Comment: Okay thanks it's work but the data not distinct. I must distinct the data

Comment: Not distinct in what sense? What needs to be distinct? you can pass an argument to the `distinct` function to specify what should be distinct, without argument it just makes sure of distinct objects (I.e. distinct primary key).

Comment: The name of `gejala` i want to be distinct. Before i use `def __init__` the `forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Gejala.objects.filter(gejala__icontains = qry).distinct().order_by('gejala'), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=False)` the name of `gejala` distinct. After i use `def __init___` the name of `gejala` not distinct

Comment: Then use `distinct('gelaja')`. I said in my previous comment you can pass that as argument.

Comment: `NotSupportedError at /diagnosis/results/
DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend` this is the error

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: My database sqlite